# When esc is pressed on fullscreen mode, throw a alert message in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

```
 @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    let keyPressed = event.keyCode;
    if (keyPressed === 27) {
      alert('Esc Key was pressed,go back to fullscreen mode');
    }
}
```

**Above is my event handler**

```
 openFullscreen() {
            if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
              this.elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
              /* Firefox */
              this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
              /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
              this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();

            } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
              /* IE/Edge */
              this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
```

**This is my code to open page in fullscreen mode. When the user presses esc button, I want to throw a error message.But the code I've tried is not working in fullscreen mode Please guide me in doing that. Thanks in advance**

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'd try `event.preventDefault()` and/or `event.stopPropagation()`. Note that even that may not be enough: your code gets keypresses when the browser decides it does, and it may decide to exit fullscreen before forwarding them to you. Also note that this practice you are attempting is poor UX: the user will not be happy if you don't let them exit fullscreen (among other things, `alert` is blocking).

Comment: I'm building a 'test system'. So I don't want the test taker to exit fullscreen mode, to avoid malpractice. Is there any way to disable ESC button on fullscreen mode?? @JaredSmith

Comment: Maybe, but you're totally at the mercy of the browser, there's nothing in the Javascript or HTML standards that I know of that says they have to let you do that, and nothing that guarantees that even if it works right now that it will stay that way and a browser update won't break it. If you really want to build this as a webpage, you apparently *can* run chrome [in kiosk mode](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+chrome+in+kiosk+mode&oq=use+chrome+in+kiosk+mode&aqs=chrome..69i57.4500j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) as long as the test computers are set up correctly.

Comment: And by the way, I'm glad browsers do so. For the same reasons you have a check box on alerts that allow the user to stop getting more alerts. I remember the time when the "alert spamming" on exit was the simple way for malicious website to force you click on something.

Comment: Any other idea other than this to prevent user from opening other browsers and tabs while attending test ??